# Angular json value not displayed in textbox

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

Im new to Angular and I can't figure out whats going on here.
I have a MVC Controller which gives me the correct value such as {PostalContactPerson : jeff}
however my Angualar view does not recognise the value on page load in the input box.

How can i get the value into the textbox please? Im perplexed why it's 'blank' when the other values are displayed from the same Form Group.

**Form.component.ts**

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any = null;



 this.arService.get(id, true)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.ar = data;
                    this.attachments = this.ar.attachments.filter(e => e.type == Enums.AttachmentType.Normal);
                    **this.data = this.ensureData(data.formData);
                    this.ar.formData = this.data;**

  this.stationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
    "businessNumbersGroup": formBuilder.group({
      "acn": [this.data.acn],
      "icn": [this.data.icn],
      "postalcontactperson": [this.data.postaladdress],
    }, ),
  });
}

ensureData(data: any): any {
        if (data == null) {
            data = {};
        }

 if (!data["postalcontactperson"]) {
        data["postalcontactperson"] = { state: "" };
    }
```

**form.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="stationInformationForm.controls['businessNumbersGroup']">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>ACN</label>
        <div class="form-description">Specify if applicable</div>
        <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !stationInformationForm.controls['businessNumbersGroup'].valid && (stationInformationForm.controls['businessNumbersGroup'].controls['acn'].touched || workflowSections[0].submitted)}" formControlName="acn" [(ngModel)]="data.acn"
          class="form-control" />
        <hr/>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>postalcontactperson</label>
        <div class="form-description">Specify if applicable</div>
        <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !stationInformationForm.controls['businessNumbersGroup'].valid && (stationInformationForm.controls['businessNumbersGroup'].controls['PostalContactPerson'].touched || workflowSections[0].submitted)}" formControlName="PostalContactPerson"
          [(ngModel)]="data.postalcontactperson" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**MVC Model**

```
      public static AnnualReturnModel Create(AnnualReturn annualReturn)
            {
               return new AnnualReturnModel
                {
                    Id = annualReturn.Id,
                    FormData = annualReturn.FormData,
PostalContactPerson = annualReturn.FormData.PostalContactPerson,
    }
}
```

**MVC Form Data**

```
 public class AnnualReturnFormData
    {
        public int? ActiveSectionIndex { get; set; }

        #region Station Information
        public string LesseeNames { get; set; }

        //Postal Address
        public string PostalContactPerson { get; set; }
}
```

json result of above:

```
{"ActiveSectionIndex":0,"LesseeNames":"aaa","PostalContactPerson":"aa","PostalPosition":"aa","PostalEmail":"aa","PostalPhone":"aa","StationContactPerson":"aaa"}
```

[debugging description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNyBm.jpg)

On page load, my ACN is shown in the textbox but the PostalContactPerson is not. why?

When I put an alert on the site, the contact person does not show my value.
alert(this.data.acn); //shows me a value of 22222
alert("contact person=" + this.data.postalcontactperson); //shows undefined

Any suggestions please? what am I missing, the JSON value is shown correctly when i check the database.
Any suggestions are Much appreciated. what am i missing with the ngModel?

Ive updated the code to the below:
**form.component.html**

```
 <div [formGroup]="stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup']">
            <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Contact Person</label>
                  <input type="text" formControlName="postalcontactperson"class="form-control" value={{annualReturn.postalcontactperson}} /> <!--value={{annualReturn.postalcontactperson}}-->

               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                <label>Position</label>
                <input type="text" formControlName="postalposition" class="form-control" />
                <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="!stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].valid && (stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].get('postalposition').touched || workflowSections[0].submitted)">You must specify Position</div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
               <label>Email</label>
               <input type="text" formControlName="postalemail" class="form-control" />
               <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="!stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].valid && (stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].get('postalemail').touched || workflowSections[0].submitted)">You must specify email</div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
              <label>Phone</label>
              <input type="text" formControlName="postalphone" class="form-control" />
              <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="!stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].valid && (stationInformationForm.controls['postalAddressGroup'].get('postalphone').touched || workflowSections[0].submitted)">You must specify phone</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**form.component.ts**

```
 var id = this.route.snapshot.params['param'];
        if (id != null) {
            this.arService.get(param, true)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.annualReturn = data;
                    this.attachments = this.annualReturn.attachments.filter(e => e.type == Enums.AttachmentType.Normal);
                    this.data = this.ensureData(data.formData);
                    this.annualReturn.formData = this.data;

                    this.dateConfig.disableUntil = { year: this.annualReturn.year - 1, month: 6, day: 30 };
                    this.dateConfig.disableSince = { year: this.annualReturn.year, month: 7, day: 1 };
                    
                  //  this.testprop = this.data.postalcontactperson;
    
                    this.stationInformationForm = formBuilder.group({
                        "survey.region": [this.data.survey.region],
                        "lesseeNames": [this.data.stationName, Validators.required],
                       // "somethingfancy": [this.data.postalcontactperson],
                       "postalcontactperson": [this.data.postalcontactperson],

                         "postalAddressGroup": formBuilder.group({
                             "postalcontactperson": [this.data.postalcontactperson, Validators.required],
                             "postalposition": [this.data.postalposition, Validators.required],
                             "postalemail": [this.data.postalemail, Validators.required],
                             "postalphone": [this.data.postalphone, Validators.required],
                         }, ),
```

Comment: How are you getting the value of ac,icn , postaladdress

Comment: if (id != null) {
            this.arService.get(id, true)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    this.loading = false;
                    this.ar = data;
                    this.attachments = this.ar.attachments.filter(e => e.type == Enums.AttachmentType.Normal);
                    this.data = this.ensureData(data.formData);
                    this.ar.formData = this.data;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the incorrect `formControlName` in the template file. It's `postalcontactperson` not `PostalContactPerson` . Observe the Capitals `P...C...P...`. And better not to use `[(ngModel)]` as you already using `Reactive Forms`. FYI, refer below changes

### Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3rkgpf?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Typescript file**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  addressForm: FormGroup;
  stationInformationForm: FormGroup;
  data: any = {
    acn: 1,
    icn: 2,
    postaladdress: {
      contactperson: "Michael",
      address: "Some Address"
    }
  };

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.stationInformationForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      businessNumbersGroup: this.formBuilder.group({
        acn: [this.data.acn, Validators.required],
        icn: [this.data.icn, Validators.required],
        postalcontactperson: [this.data.postaladdress.contactperson, Validators.required]
      })
    });

    // Getting inner form group
    this.addressForm = this.stationInformationForm.get(
      "businessNumbersGroup"
    ) as FormGroup;

    // Getting Form Changes instead of using `[(ngModel)]`
    this.addressForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

**Template file**

```
<div [formGroup]="addressForm">
    <label>ACN</label>
    <div class="form-description">Specify if applicable</div>
    <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.valid && addressForm.get('acn').touched }" formControlName="acn" class="form-control" />
    <hr />
    <label>postalcontactperson</label>
    <div class="form-description">Specify if applicable</div>
    <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'has-error': !addressForm.valid && addressForm.get('postalcontactperson').touched }" formControlName="postalcontactperson" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer. All the data is from a json stream of Form data. with the below code, can you suggest why the data.postaladdress would be blank? Ill add the MVC bit to further explain

Comment: Hey @Michael instead of adding here, can you update the question? ;)

Comment: There's something that i missed, ill update the original question but as soon as I updated the ensure object above, the text fields appear now with the values of [object, object]. It must of been the ensureData(). Any ideas why they say Object, Object?

Comment: Hey Sivakumar, your getting me on the right track but now the postalcontactperson object is null from my json. How could it be null when the value is assigned in the data.postalcontactperson from the json above (in the form data)? The line  this.addressForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data)); is so helpful. Is there one that shows the equivalent of values loaded at display time too?

Comment: Ive added an image to show whats going on. Im expecting a postalcontactperson object from my json to be loaded at runtime but i get 'null'. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you getting null on console.log from subscription of valueChanges?

Comment: What is that image exactly refers to?

Comment: Yes, im getting null for the postalAddressGroup objects with this line when it loads AddressForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log(data));  the image is my values returned from the MVC controller, angular cannot see the values in the postalAddressGroup and the Input is still = null.

Comment: In your example with  data: any = {
    acn: 1,
    icn: 2,
    postaladdress: {
      contactperson: "Michael",
      address: "Some Address"
    }  ,    the postal address bit is 'null' from my MVC controller from angualars perspective. So I can't bind the values to the form. Do i need ngValue?. so from my data.postalcontactperson it's always null

Comment: Ive updated the question, the items in the below group are always null.   
              "postalAddressGroup": formBuilder.group({
                             "postalcontactperson": [this.data.postalcontactperson, Validators.required],
                             "postalposition": [this.data.postalposition, Validators.required],
                             "postalemail": [this.data.postalemail, Validators.required],
                             "postalphone": [this.data.postalphone, Validators.required],
                         }, ),

Comment: So, as you said, you are not getting value for postalcontactperson from MVC controller itself. Can you check at backend side why it is happening?

Comment: but when I step through the MVC Server project, the value is there. Does my MVC contoller need to have an object named 'postalAddressGroup'?

Comment: Can you share image of network call related to postalcontactperson. Are you getting the value in the network call? Try to share image of network tab with the call in open state and preview tab opened ;) let's check what is happening

Comment: Ive posted a debug shot from the server side that shows the objects exist in the FormData

Comment: What `this.ensureData(data.formData);` will do? I think you are getting properties from backend with capital letters. But you are using normal letter without caps!!!

Comment: Can you console.log(this.data) after the line `this.data = this.ensureData(data.formData);` ? and can share the screenshot ;)

Comment: I followed your advice and put in the log for ensure data and it showed me the value. Then that told me the MVC bit was correct. Then i specifically focused on the caps and reworked it and it works!!!! Im so happy, I had been stuck on this for a while. I want to Thankyou so much for your time. Now i  just need to update it :) that would be this line right - >   this.stationInformationForm.controls["postalContactPerson"].updateValueAndValidity();

Comment: @Michael really glad as my answer and suggestions helped you ;). If you want to update a control, you need to use either `patchValue()` or `setValue()` on the control. So it would be -> `this.stationInformationForm.controls["postalContactPerson"].patchValue(<any value>);`